# Read dynamodb code not being executed in exports.handler in lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function written in node.js that returns a QRCode Image. I am also trying to read a value from the Dynamodb. However, the console logs inside it do not seem to be executed which makes me think the code is not being run.

I suspect this is due to so synchronization issues. But I am not sure what to do to fix it. The code is below:

```
var qrImage = require('qr-image');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    var path = event.path;
    var drugId = path.replace(/\//g, '');

    var params = {
    TableName: 'QRCodeInfo',
    Key: {
      "DrugId" : "1234"
    }
  };

  docClient.get(params, function(err,data) {  //does not get executed
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

    return sendRes(200,drugId); //this works. Image is seen.
};

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  //console.log(body);
  const svg_string = qrImage.imageSync(body, { type: 'svg', size: 10 });
  var response = {
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/svg+xml"
    },
    body: svg_string
  };
  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably exiting the lambda before the callback of the dynamodb call has had a chance to execute.

Try calling `callback(null, data)` in the callback of the dynamo call, after your `console.log` and similar in the err scenario e.g. `callback(err)`

You do not exit a lambda by calling `return`, you should be calling `callback()` (that's why it's available as the 3rd argument of the lambda)  see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback

Comment: Yes this is my thought as well. But how would I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Quite new to node.js/Javascript

Comment: Okay will try that.

Comment: But then how would I get my QRCode Image to display? I would have to use return so that when anyone access the link, they will see a QRCode Image.

Comment: Hard to read on my phone, but it's probably `callback(null, sendRes(200, drugId))` you need then. Basically just treat `callback()` as the mechanism to return data to the caller. First arg is an error payload, second arg is a success payload

Comment: Wow it all worked once I started using call backs. You are a genius. So many hours wasted by me :(

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Definitely read up on lambdas, they have a few quirks that can waste a lot of time if you assume certain things. Another quirk is that callback does not straight away exit from the lambda, you will find the next lines of code may still execute. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks I will! I had a really quick follow up question. Is it possible to wait for one callback to be done before the other callback?

Comment: Open up a separate question and i'll surely have a look, not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I have made a separate question.